# VB.NET and IBMi SQL dr.hasrows isn't showing rows (that I know exist)

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm running into a problem where I'm using a dr.hasrows If statement, and it is returning as false (when I am 100% positive it's true).
I'm pretty new at both VB and (IBM)SQL, but I have had this command work fine in the past.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim SQL As String = "Select * from testlib.hrcontra where @HRAART=HRAART and @HRASEC=HRASEC and @HRAPAR=HRAPAR and @HRASEQ=HRASEQ and @HRARED=HRARED"
    Using cmd As New iDB2Command(SQL, CN)
        cmd.DeriveParameters()
        cmd.Parameters("@HRAART").Value = SCRHRAART
        cmd.Parameters("@HRASEC").Value = SCRHRASEC
        cmd.Parameters("@HRAPAR").Value = SCRHRAPAR
        cmd.Parameters("@HRASEQ").Value = SCRHRASEQ
        'cmd.Parameters("@HRARED").Value = SCRHRARED
        Try
            Using dr As iDB2DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                dr.Read()
                If dr.HasRows = True Then
                    MsgBox("Table already exists!")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End Using
        Catch ex As iDB2Exception
            Form1.HandleError("An error occurred on cmd.ExecuteReader()", ex)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End Using
```

Do I need to be certain to use ALL fields (even non-key)?  Or, can I just use the 4 key fields in this situation (which is the goal).  I've tried working both the SQL and VB.net angles to the solution and have gotten nowhere.e

Comment: Probably it is just a typo, but your command is short of one parameter @HRARED

Comment: I intentionally removed @HRARED in-order to not have it compared, as the 80-character long allowed entry will most likely ALWAYS be different from an existing entry.  I just want to compare the key fields (HRAART, HRASEC, HRAPAR, HRASEQ).

Comment: HOLY CRAP, you mad me re-examine the SQL and realize I was comparing for HRARED in my SQL.  I removed it from the SQL command and now it works!

THANK YOU, Steve!

(note: cannot answer my own question, someone else will have to add it.)

Answer (score 0):

HOLY CRAP, you made me re-examine the SQL and realize I was comparing for HRARED in my SQL.  I removed it from the SQL command and now it works!

THANK YOU, Steve!

**Solution: Double check to make sure your SQL and VB match, kids!**